# accessing and modifying matrix element

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix

I basically want to do the following

```
A = Array[0 &, {4, 9}];
a = {2, 3};
A[[a[[1]], a[[2]]]] = 1;
A // MatrixForm
```

but with less cumbersome notation.(i.e. change line 3 to something nicer)!

I get the position as a pair (a list with 2 elements) and want to change the matrix entry at the position which that pair encodes. The pair is returned by the functions "RandomChoice" and "Position".

Thanks for the help!

Comment: `ReplacePart[A, a -> 1]`?

Comment: `ReplacePart[A, a -> 1]` will create a *new* matrix that is what you want. You can assign that to `A`.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: kinda need to do this a lot so creating a new matrix each time will probably turn out to be too time-consuming?

Comment: `SparseArray[{2, 3} -> 1, {4, 9}];
% // MatrixForm`

Comment: `A = Array[0 &, {4, 9}];
A[[2, 3]] = 1;
A // MatrixForm`

Comment: Thanks, though I just made this matrix as an example to post here. I only want to change line 3 if possible. I get the position "a" with the help of the "Position" function and the matrix "A" is filled somewhere else (not all entries are zero).

Comment: `A[[3]] = {1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 17, 23}` and  `(A) // MatrixForm` ?

Comment: I have updated my answer for the pair scenario.

Comment: Try: `A[[Sequence @@ a]] = 1`

Comment: @DanielHuber THANKS!!! This is exactly what I was searching for!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is my best interpretation of what the OP wants.

```
alist = RandomChoice[{"banana", "apple", "orange", "grapes"}, 9]

{"grapes", "orange", "orange", "banana", "orange", "orange", \
"grapes", "banana", "banana"}
```

Suppose the positions of "orange" have to be detected.

```
pos = Flatten@Position[alist, "orange"]
```

> {2, 3, 5, 6}

```
A[[3, pos]] = 1
A // MatrixForm
```

$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccccccccc}
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

---

**EDIT**

Assuming that a pair of (valid) numbers is to be used to change the entry at that index to 13:

```
pos = {3, 8}  (* received from some function *)
A[[First@pos, Last@pos]] = 13
A // MatrixForm
```

$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccccccccc}
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 13 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: What info? I just want to change line 3 in the example code I've given above. My problem: I have a matrix and a pair and I want to change the entry of the matrix corresponding to my pair.

Comment: Cool, thanks! I guess this is slightly more readable.

Comment: Thanks for the accept. @PeterMüller. The idea behind editing is that your post should be self-contained so that future visitors to the page should be able to read and understand the question without having to sift through the comments. See you later.